# Selenium + Java. Как передать не статическую переменную внутри xPath?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Всем привет. Мне необходимо передать переменную из файла properties `computeEngine.getMachineSeries()` в xPath. Однако это не получается сделать, из-за следующей ошибки : “Attribute value must be constant”.
Можно ли это как-нибудь обойти? Задать параметр в xpath другим способом?

```
@FindBys({@FindBy(xpath = "//md-option//div[@class='md-text ng-binding'][contains(text(), '" + computeEngine.getMachineSeries()+ "')]")})
List<WebElement> seriesOptionNOne;
```

Comment: Попробуйте вынести значение `computeEngine.getMachineSeries()` в `final` переменную